# IVRS response recorder

Tags: mysql, ivr

I have a web based system built on php & mysql where the we have a complaint box with 5 different types of complain which are logged over phone by an operator.

i want to build a system where the caller will press buttons on the phone like an IVRS system to book the complaint and a unique complaint number is sent to the caller.

like complain calls are made to 1905 and then a language menu is heard.

like 1 for english
then please dial your std code 
user dials 456 
then please enter your phone number 
user dials 87657672
then please dial issue type  1 for phone, 2 for broadband etc.
user dials 2.
please select a complaint type:  1 for link absent, 2 for link unstable...
user dials 2

i want all the above to happen over a IVR system and then store the selections in a mysql database table called tickets.

how can i go about to achieve this.

please guide.

thanks & regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your question correctly you have an operator using a web-app to register complaints and you want to replace the operator with an IVR? Do you have an IVR system selected?

The standard for bulding voice menus in IVR's is called VoiceXML. You can find that standard on the w3c website.

As for IVR's you could have a look at IBM's WebSphere Voice Response or Genesys Voice Portal. If you search a bit you'll find enough information to get a better idea on the possibilities.